# NuGet doesn't show all supported frameworks under the main header

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

The listing for my NuGet package [SoftCircuits.CsvParser](https://github.com/SoftCircuits/CsvParser) shows it supports .NET 5.0 and .NET Standard 2.0.

[image]

But when I look at the dependencies, it shows it supports .NET 6.0 as well.

[image]

Can anyone tell me why .NET 6.0 doesn't show up under the title? I have all three versions specified in my project file.

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net5.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

What am I missing for .NET 6.0 to show up under the main heading?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just the intended behavior of Nuget.org. If you hover over the tags underneath the title, you get a tooltip that says:

> This package is compatible with this framework or higher.

[image]

So it would seem that these tags show the *minimum supported version* of a given framework, with the implication being that every subsequent version is also supported (hence why your package has a tag for .NET 5.0, but not .NET 6.0 - the latter is implied).

If you look a popular package like Newtonsoft.Json, you'll see the same behavior. It has [many `TargetFrameworks` listed in its `.csproj`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.csproj#L3), but only shows ".NET Standard 1.0" and ".NET Framework 2.0" on its [Nuget Gallery page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

Comment: What's weird is someone forked one of my GitHub projects, changed the name to theor own name, and put that on NuGet. And it sure seemed like their version did show .NET 6.0 under the header. Unfortunately, I complained to them and they've since taken it down. I will see if I can find examples of that.